# Build an Angular 7 app together with a react app webpack configuration

Tags: angular, reactjs, npm, webpack, package.json

I am facing a challenge with one of our angular app.

Basically, we have standard Angular app, inside the "apps" folder I need to place a 
React app. at the same level of the angular app.

The folder structure will be something like:

- apps(main angular project folder)
- - Angular app
- - - src
- - - etc..
- - React app
- - - src
- - - package.json
- - - etc.
- package.json
- angular.json
- etc...

When I build the app(the main angular app) I also need to compile the react app so that the result will be something like.

- dist
- - angular-app
- - react-app

How can I set up web-pack to achieve this result in one command?

My confusion comes from the fact that the angular app has a package.json and the react app(placed inside the angular app) also have a package.json.
How can I make them communicate?

I appreciate any help

Comment: You might need to look at micro-frontend solutions which enables you to use multiple frameworks together: https://medium.com/@tomsoderlund/micro-frontends-a-microservice-approach-to-front-end-web-development-f325ebdadc16

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I was hoping there was some sort of configuration to tell web-pack to build using a different package.json or similar solutions. I will definitely check this